# Can you do this?

Tags: cipher

3 2 1 Go

Here the key has already been viewed, be fooled you will, taken from the left to the right it shall be revealed!

> ily all sha llh aou

**Hint:**

> {3} to 13th

Comment: Provide an explanation for why you downvoted this 9 10 11 12 13, if you may of course

Comment: Yoda I see......

Answer (score 5):

It's:

> You shall all hail
>  Because I can read it scrambled, but don't see how "3 2 1 Go" makes it so.

EDIT: Or is it, thanks to @manshu and @ABcDexter

> Shall hail all you.
>  Because that starts in the 3rd group grabbing "sha llh a" which needs "il".
>  The gets "all" from the second group and finally "you" from the first.

Comment: Almost there...

Comment: Words were made, but sense they don't make

Comment: @Mr.Derpinthoughton "You all shall hail"??

Comment: @Mr.Derpinthoughton "Shall hail you all..." ?

Comment: "All shall hail you"?

Comment: @IanMacDonald "Shall all hail you?"?!? :) )

Comment: "You hail all shall"?

Comment: @IanMacDonald "Shall all you hail?"

Comment: @IanMacDonald Only $4! - 8 = 16$ iterations to go :) )

Answer (score 3):

**Explanation**:

> "Can you do this?" has **13** visible characters 
> 3 2 1 go => the number **3** is right above "Here"
> Here...
> The sentence was divided into 5 pieces made of three letters each
> ily all sha llh aou
> Until this point a little bit of guessing is needed
> Hint:
> {3} to 13th
> {ily} all sha llh....  a...  ou
> .........................13th
> **{3} to 13th** means a group `{}` containing `3` letters to the `13th` thirteenth position
> all sha llh  a{ily}    ou
> Thus:
> ***all shall hail you***

Comment: *sigh* beat me to it.

Comment: Ah, we would have got in at most $4!$ tries :) )

Comment: This makes no sense. Can you explain more clearly?

Comment: @Deusovi There are 4 words. You can create all possible iterations of 4 things in $4! = 24$ ways

Comment: @Evans: The answer, not $4!$.

Comment: @HughMeyers This answer was provided by the person that posed the puzzle in the first place. I wouldn't really consider that a "beat me to it" scenario. :)

Comment: @IanMacDonald Me neither, the author is certainly a cheater in my point of view :)

Comment: @Deusovi Ah, now I gotcha. I think it's got something to do with "Can you do this?" having 13 letters if you don't count spaces but do count '?' as a "letter".  Then going 13 places into "ily all sha llh aou", again not counting spaces - luckily no punctuation marks to worry about. You land up here "ily all sha llh a^ou". Then you take the 3rd... or 2nd.. no the 1st group of 3 letters "ily" and plonk it in there for some reason?!?  Go, I suppose means that in a cryptic way. Sorry I got lost at this point and started trying random permutations :P